# How to solve: "activityLevel be an Int that will represent a scoring 1-10 of how active they are. Implement this now."

Tags: swift, swift3

HI guys I try to solve this exercise:
For most apps you'll need to have a data structure to hold information about a user. Create a User struct that has properties for basic information about a user. At a minimum, it should have properties to represent a user's name, age, height, weight, and activity level. You could do this by having name be a String, age be an Int, height and weight be of type Double, and activityLevel be an Int that will represent a scoring 1-10 of how active they are. Implement this now.

but I don't understand when he says: activityLevel be an Int that will represent a scoring 1-10 of how active they are. Implement this now.

I don't know if it's right.

below post my code:

```
struct User {
    let name : String
    var age : Int
    var height : Double
    var weight : Double
    var activityLevel = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are saying that your activityLevel be an Int, that can only be the values 1-10:

```
struct User {
    let name : String
    var age : Int
    var height : Double
    var weight : Double
    var activityLevel : Int
}
```

And then when you try and set the value, you would need to enforce that it is in the correct range:

```
init?(name: String, age: Int, height: Double, weight: Double, activityLevel: Int){
    guard activityLevel > 0 && activityLevel < 11 else { return nil }

    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.height = height
    self.weight = weight
    self.activityLevel = activityLevel
}
```